# How to accept password in terminal without showing password

Tags: c, linux, security

I am a Linux user and I always see that whenever I type my password in the terminal, it is accepted properly by the system but the password is not shown.

How do I achieve this in a **C program**?

Comment: Learn also about [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by the help of `getpass`. But [man getpass](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpass) saying

> This function is obsolete. Do not use it. If you want to read input without terminal echoing enabled, see the description of the ECHO flag in termios(3).

This code will work(This code is exact copy of other `SO` post)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct termios oflags, nflags;
    char password[128];

    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
    nflags = oflags;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSADRAIN, &nflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\npassword(Echo Disabled) : ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;
    printf("Entered password        : %s\n", password);

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &oflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\npassword(Echo Enabled)  : ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;
    printf("Entered password        : %s\n", password);

    return 0;
}
```

Explantion :

1. Get the terminal current attributes in `termios structure` using `tcgetattr()` for restore terminal attributes later .
2. Create new `termios structure` and set Disable echo flag in `termios structure` member.
3. Set the new terminal attributes from new `termios structure` using `tcsetattr`.
4. Set the old saved terminal attributes again using `tcsetattr` when you want enable echo. That is restoring the terminal back to old status

[Further detail man tcgetattr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr)

Comment: Thanks for keeping me from using obsolete methods!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getpass](http://www.linux.com/learn/docs/man/3177-getpass3)

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
char *password = getpass("Password: ");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getpass() or another way is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct termios oflags, nflags;
    char password[64];

    /* disabling echo */
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &oflags);
    nflags = oflags;
    nflags.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    nflags.c_lflag |= ECHONL;

    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &nflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("password: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
    password[strlen(password) - 1] = 0;
    printf("you typed '%s'\n", password);

    /* restore terminal */
    if (tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &oflags) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```